# csh environment variable execute

Tags: environment-variables, space, csh

I'm building a command line up in a tcsh shell variable, something like

```
set cmd  = "/usr/local/bin/rsync "
set parm = "--verbose --acls --times --links "
set src  = "/spindle/to\ be\ backed-up "
set dest = "/mnt/backup21 "

set final = "$cmd $parm $src $dest"

$final
```

and I'd like the last line to execute the command.  I can get this to execute, but always with the error

```
rsync: link_stat "/spindle/to\" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

It doesn't seem to properly see the space in the path.  I tried multiple \ in that line, still didn't work.  Suggestions?

Comment: That's not an *environment* variable, it's just a shell variable. Environment variables are set with `setenv`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd seriously consider finding a different way to do this. csh is widely considered to be a poor shell for programming; see the classic article [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). I've been using csh and tcsh for more decades than I care to admit, and I still have to resort to trial and error to answer questions like this.

But for your immediate question, `eval` seems to work. Replace the line

```
$final
```

by

```
eval $final
```